# Issues loading data in from xml using TinyXml2

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

I am trying to make a function in my application that can load in an object through attributes in an xml file. I would like to use TinyXML2 as I hear it is pretty easy and quick for games.

Currently I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Level>
    <Pulsator starttime="0" type="0" higherradius="100" lowerradius="10" time="60" y="500" x="300" bpm="60"/>
</Level>
```

Each attribute of the Pulsator is a variable in my Pulsator class. I use the followign function to import my Pulsators and add them to an vector of objects.

```
void Game::LoadLevel(string filename)
{
    tinyxml2::XMLDocument level;
    level.LoadFile(filename.c_str());
    tinyxml2::XMLNode* root = level.FirstChild();
    tinyxml2::XMLNode* childNode = root->FirstChild();

    while (childNode)
    {
        Pulsator* tempPulse = new Pulsator();
        float bpm;
        float type;
        std::string::size_type sz;

        tinyxml2::XMLElement* data = childNode->ToElement();
        string inputdata = data->Attribute("bpm");
        bpm = std::stof(inputdata, &sz);

        if (type == 0)
        {
            tempPulse->type = Obstacle;
            tempPulse->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Black));
        }
        if (type == 1)
        {
            tempPulse->type = Enemy;
            tempPulse->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Red));
        }
        if (type == 2)
        {
            tempPulse->type = Score;
            tempPulse->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Green));
        }
        else
        {
            tempPulse->type = No_Type;
        }

        objects.push_back(tempPulse);
    }
}
```

Every time I get to the root node, it loads in incorrectly and the childnode becomes null.
Am I using this incorrectly or is there an issue with my XML file?

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't correctly specify the child it wants. You want the first XMLElement, not the first child. To do that, use this code when you get the childNode:

```
tinyxml2::XMLElement* childNode = root->FirstChildElement();
```

And that saves you the cast later. (You don't need, and shouldn't use, the ToElement()).